# How to use dbName and collection prefix using quartz properties by implementing jobstore

Tags: mongodb, properties, quartz-scheduler, job-scheduling

Quick Question,
I know we can configure dbName and collection prefix in Quartz property file (like following), But How to access those properties by implementing JobStore (where I use mongo) interface in any class.

## Mongo database name

org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource=quartzdatabase

## collection prefix

org.quartz.jobStore.collectionPrefix=prefix_

How to use these property in java by implementing jobstore (where I use mongo) and overriding the methods in it, I know there is a method called initialise() in jobstore, Is it possible to get those properties in it.

Guys, Waiting for ur reply.

Thanks and Regards,
Harry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by myself, We need to use the setter and getter for the corresponding field (i.e) dataSource and Collectionprefix in the class where you have implemented JobStore.

Thanks and Regards,
Harry